# converting cross sectional slides to vertical section in CT scan images

Tags: matlab

I have 76 2D cross sectional slices of CT scan images.
I want to generate a vertical section by those slices.

Can somebody please give me an idea or tip about how to do it?

- a sample of CT slices: http://i58.tinypic.com/2uf3v9d.png
- a sample of what I'm looking for: http://i59.tinypic.com/dgnmfq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all the scans into a single 3D array

```
CT3D = zeros(SizeY, SizeX, NumScans);
% read data into CT3D, depending on your data format...
```

and then get a slice along a vertical section by indexing, for example:

```
sliceXZ = CT3D(100, :, :);
sliceYZ = CT3D(:, 150, :);
```